# Python 3. Как получить доступ к словарю запущенного из другого модуля?

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть готовый сервер Flask где запускаются nlp модели. Пока к нему было подключено 5 устройств, не было проблем, потом мы увеличили это количество до 15 и тут началась проблема с производительностью. Решили увеличить количество ядер на этом сервере с 12 до 24, но получили прибавку производительности в районе 20%. Решили опробовать другой метод, запустили 3 сервера через Gunicorn и taskset --cpu-list (выдав по 8 ядер каждому серверу) на разных портах с ограничение по 5 устройств на сервер, тут производительность выросла в почти в 2 раза, стала приблизительно такой же как на сервере с 12 ядрами когда было 5 устройств. Но тут возникла другая проблема, каждый сервер запускал свои модели изолировано друга от друга и потребление озу выросло в 3 раза.

Модели загружаются в словарь по этому коду

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import os
import learning

app = Flask(__name__)

models_list_name = os.listdir('models')

global_dict_models = {}

for token in models_list_name:
    try:
        tok, n_class, model_type, typ, h_layer = token.split('.')

        t, model = learning.get_model(model_type, typ)

        n_class = int(n_class)
        h_layer = int(h_layer)
        model = learning.NewModel(model, n_class, typ, h_layer)
        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join('models', token), map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
        
        print(model, tok)
        with open(tok, 'r') as f:
            label = f.read().split('\n')
        print(label)
        global_dict_models[tok] = (t, model, label)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

а когда нужен предикт, то запрос просто обращается к словарю

```
t, model, labels = global_dict_models[token]
x = t.encode_plus(text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=512, truncation=True, padding="max_length", return_tensors='pt')
    
output = torch.sigmoid(model(x['input_ids'].squeeze(1), x['attention_mask'])).detach().cpu().numpy()
```

Модели на всех серверах одни и те же. Хочу сделать единый модуль с загрузкой моделей, где формируется словарь и что бы каждый сервер через функцию просто к нему обращался.

Пробовал создать отдельный модуль по такому принципу

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import os
import learning

app = Flask(__name__)

models_list_name = os.listdir('models')

global_dict_models = {}

def load_models():
    for token in models_list_name:
        try:
            tok, n_class, model_type, typ, h_layer = token.split('.')
    
            t, model = learning.get_model(model_type, typ)
    
            n_class = int(n_class)
            h_layer = int(h_layer)
            model = learning.NewModel(model, n_class, typ, h_layer)
            model.load_state_dict(torch.load(os.path.join('models', token), map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
            
            print(model, tok)
            with open(tok, 'r') as f:
                label = f.read().split('\n')
            print(label)
            global_dict_models[tok] = (t, model, label)
        except ValueError:
            pass
  

def dict_models(token):
    t, model, labels = global_dict_models[token]
    return t, model, labels    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_models()
    print('Start')
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000", threaded=True, processes=1)
```

И тут возникла проблема, что не получается прочитать словарь, который был запущен в другом модуле.

Подскажите, как загрузить словарь один раз и иметь к нему доступ из других модулей? Или как решить эту проблему другим способом?

Comment: В Питоне с этим сложно всё как-то. Проще всего мне кажется подгружать модели с диска по мере необходимости. Зачем вам держать все модели всю дорогу в памяти? Подгружаете нужную модель, делаете предсказание и освобождаете память.

Comment: Предикты идут постоянно, поэтому приходиться держать в памяти модели. Так то это не дорого держать в памяти 4 модели, это занимает ~5 гб, но когда 3 сервера и каждый грузит модели отдельно, это превращается уже в 15гб. Даже с 15гб нет проблем, на это есть ресурсы, но все таки хотелось бы оптимизации, но в питоне походу с этим плохо

Comment: А если собрать статистику и раскидать модели равномерно по серверам? Грубо говоря, вот есть модели с частотой использования 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. Раскидываете их по серверам так: сервер 1 - модели 9+4+3, сервер 2 - модели 8+5+2, сервер 3 - модели 7+6+1, получается нагрузка на сервера 16, 15, 14 - почти равномерно. Ну или другую схему можно какую-то придумать, я просто беру в каждой группе из n значений i-е с начала, i-е с конца, i-е с начала...

Comment: Основной смысл - не держать все модели на всех серверах, а разбросать модели так, чтобы все сервера были равномерно востребованы. Если какая-то модель супер востребована - ок, грузить её на нескольких серверах и по очереди кидать запросы на них. Вообще балансировка - тема интересная, но я ей глубоко не занимался.

Comment: @CrazyElf В этом и сложность, что не знаешь в каком момент времени, нужна будет определенная модель. Если создать по такому принципу, это будет стоить дороже в плане озу, потому, что в память загружается еще базовая модель pytorch, весом 1 гб. И получается мы имеем 3 сервера, где 4 модели потребляют 4гб+1гб базовая модель, и того выходит 15 гб, а если сделать 8 серверов, выделяя по 1 модели на 2 сервера, это выходит дороже 16гб, и вместе с тем увеличивается отклик, потому, что в определенный момент понадобиться всем модель на 1-2 сервере.

Comment: Ну тогда я бы вам посоветовал сходить в сообщество ODS и у них там в слаке спросить у тех, кто модели крутит, что делать в такой ситуации. Всё-таки вопрос довольно специфичный. Да, и ещё - а что у вас за входные данные, может есть смысл кэшировать запрос-ответ, не повторяются ли запросы? Ну и сами модели можно кэшировать скажем последние пару моделей, тогда если пачкой пойдут запросы на одну и ту же модель, то все сервера с этим хорошо справятся. В общем, сценарии использования бы изучить не помешало.